# notepad ++ replace with regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

In notepad ++, I want to replace these:

```
gl_account_wid AS [gl_ACCT_rowid],
    location_code AS [location_code],
    location_name AS [location_name],
    location_level_1 AS [location_lvl1_name],
    location_level_2 AS [location_lvl2_name],
    location_level_3 AS [location_lvl3_name],
    location_level_4 AS [location_lvl4_name],
    location_level_5 AS [location_lvl5_name],
    location_level_6 AS [location_lvl6_name],
    location_level_7 AS [location_lvl7_name],
    location_level_8 AS [location_lvl8_name],
    location_level_9 AS [location_lvl9_name],
    w_insert_dt AS [w_created_date],
    w_update_dt AS [w_changed_date],
```

to these:

```
gl_account_wid,
    location_code,
    location_name,
    location_level_1,
    location_level_2,
    location_level_3,
    location_level_4,
    location_level_5,
    location_level_6,
    location_level_7,
    location_level_8,
    location_level_9,
    w_insert_dt,
    w_update_dt,
```

Comment: Can you include your attempt too, just so we can see if you got close to a solution yourself or what it is you are stuck on?

Comment: Have tried this: \sAS\s\[[a-z/A-Z/_]+\], can only locate part of the items

Comment: Thanks @thotwielder. You should edit that into your question for other to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. It looks like you got confused with how to escape characters that have special meaning like the opening square brackets. I managed to get your desired results through:

```
\hAS\h\[\w+\]
```

- `\h` - A horizontal whitespace character.
- `AS` - Literally "AS".
- `\h` - A horizontal whitespace character.
- `\[` - A literal opening bracket.
- `\w+` - 1+ Word-characters, equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`.
- `\]` - A literal closing bracket.

Replace with nothing.

[image]